# Error with session ini setting modification

Tags: codeigniter-3

A PHP Error was encountered

```
Severity: Warning
Message: ini_set(): A session is active. You cannot change the session module's ini settings at this time
Filename: Session/Session.php
Line Number: 316
Backtrace:
File: C:\xampp\htdocs\testing\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

```html
<?php
 session_start(); //we need to start session in order to access it through CI
class Adminlogin extends CI_Controller {

 public function _construct(){
 parent::_construct();

 //Load form helper library
 $this->load->helper('form');
 //Load form validation library
 $this->load->library('form_validation');
 //Load session library
 $this->load->library('session');
 //Load database
 $this->load->model('login_database');
 }

 //show login page
 public function index()
 {
  $this->load->view('admin_login');
 }
 //show registration page
 public function user_registration_show(){
  $this->load->view('admin_signup');
 }
 //Validate and store registration data in database
 public function new_user_registration(){

 //Check Validation for user input in SignUp form
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('admin_username', 'Username','trim|required|xss_clean');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('admin_password', 'Password','trim|required|xss_clean');
 if($this->form_validation->run()== FALSE){
  $this->load->view('admin_signup');}
 else{
  $data = array(
   'admin_username' => $this->input->post('username'),
   'admin_password' => $this->input->post('password'));
 $result = $this->login_database->registration_insert($data);
 if($result == TRUE){
  $data['message_display'] = 'Registration Successfully !';
 $this->load->view('admin_login', $data);
 }else{
  $data['message_display'] = 'Username already exist';
 $this->load->view('admin_signup',$data);
 }
 }
 }

 //Check for user login process
 public function user_login_process(){
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('admin_username','Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('admin_password','Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
 if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
 if(isset($this->session->userdata['loggen_in'])){
    $this->load->view('Admin/admin_dashboard');
 }else{
  $this->load->view('admin_login');
 }
 }else{
  $data = array(
   'admin_username' => $this->input->post('username'),
   'admin_password' => $this->input->post('password'));
 $result = $this->login_database->login($data);
 if($result == TRUE) {

 $username = $this->input->post('username');
 $result = $this->login_database->read_user_information($username);
 if($result != false){
  $session_data = array(
   'username' => $result[0]->admin_username,
   'password' => $result[0]->admin_password);
 //Add user data in session
  $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $session_data);
  $this->load->view('Admin/admin_dashboard');
 }else{
 $data = array(
  'error_message' => 'Invalid Username or Password');
 $this->load->view('admin_login',$data);
 }
 }
 }

 
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the 1st line `session_start();` or change it to..

```
// session_start(); //I do Not need this as I am using CI Sessions.
```

You are using CodeIgniters Sessions which you have loaded in your code...

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

As an Aside: 
You don't need the end `?>` in your PHP files where it is the last tag in the file.